# OpenSSH/Dropbear using MYSQL Database - Linux [ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ssh, database, dropbear

Is it possible to use MYSQL to store user accounts and use it to authenticate with your SSH (OpenSSH/Dropbear) and is it possible to use remote mysql database?

Basically, I want to use MYSQL as user database and use it to authenticate w/ expiration and if possible I want to use remote mysql database.

Comment: what you're talking about sounds like an LDAP/Kerberos implementation. It basically allows you to have a centralized storage of users and their passwords among other things. Something like Windows Active Directory.

Comment: You can also use `AuthorizedKeysCommand` in the sshd_config file to run a custom script that connects to anything as long as it prints public keys back to the console. I'm writing a Golang tool for this at the moment which isn't complete yet on SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In addition the the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` recommended by @praveen-p (highly recommended), you could use PAM-MySQL for a service (and `UsePAM=1` in sshd_config). There are better user account mechanisms and using those over MySQL is recommended.